# How to print out array of random numbers in java from method that gets even numbers and elements?

Tags: java, arrays

I was having trouble printing out my method of an array that finds only even numbers in the array and every even element in the array (location 0, 2, 4, ...)

### Program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Numbers: " + Arrays.toString(genNumber()));
    System.out.println("Even elements: " +everyEven());
    System.out.printf("Even numbers:" +getEven());
}

public static int[] genNumber(){
    int[] number = new int[10];       

    for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        number[i] = (int)(Math.random()*15 + 1);
    }

    return number;
}

public static int[] everyEven(int[] number){
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
        }
    }
    return number;
}

public static int getEven(int[] number){
    int i;
    int even=0;

    for (i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i += 2) {
        even = number[i];
    }
    return even;
}
```

Comment: If you only want to your loop to consider every 2nd element then you should have that as an increment condition and use `i=i+2` instead of just `i++`

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS but he said the array does contain random numbers and have a look at the generate method - your solution wouldn´t work.

Comment: @EthanWolfe Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Specific pages that you should read include [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please take these introductory steps and then edit your post accordingly.

Comment: @LenglBoy in the question he says he want to print "(location 0, 2, 4 etc)" - Now obviously if he want's to print every location that contains a number that is even that would be different. Just another typical unclear question i guess.

Comment: You want to use an `int[ ]` or is a `List` also ok for you?

Comment: So I understand this: `everyEven()` should return an array of all even numbers and `getEven()` is still the same. What´s the difference?

Comment: `for (i = 0 ; i < 1 ; i += 2)` . This `for` loop is useless.

Comment: Here is what he wants: `everyEven()` will return **even elements** (i.e. the even indexes like index 0, index 2, ...), and  `getEven()` will return the **even numbers**. I guess, he wants to use `int[]` instead of `List`. It will be very simple to use `List`.

Comment: @EthanWolfe: I downvote because his questions are very unclear. ... He should make his requests more clear and provide a simple example of the expected results.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand of your question, you want to print every even number at every even index. If that is the case, then the following code would be useful.

```
public String getNumbers(){
    String returnString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i+= 2){
        if(number[i] % 2 == 0)
            returnString += " " + number[i];
    }
    return returnString;
)
```

This code will return a String of all the even numbers in the array which are at an even index.

If you want to return a list of all the numbers which are either at an even index or are even numbers, then the following code segment will help you.

```
public String getNumbers() {
    String returnString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
        if(number[i] % 2 == 0 || i % 2 == 0) {
            returnString += " " + number[i];
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: You must use StringBuilder instead of String concatenation in loop!